# attempt to compare string with number - computercraft

Tags: lua, computercraft

```
    local level = 3 -- Required access level
local sideIn = "bottom" -- Keycard Input Side
local sideOut = "right" -- Redstone output side
local rsTime = 3 -- Redstone time
while true do
if disk.isPresent(sideIn) then
        term.clear()
        term.setCursorPos(1,1)
        local code = fs.open("disk/passcode.lua", "r").readAll()
        if code == nil then
        local code = 0
        else
        local code = tonumber(code)
        end
        if code >= level then
        print("> Access Granted")
        disk.eject(sideIn)
        rs.setOutput(sideOut,true)
        sleep(rsTime)
        rs.setOutput(sideOut,false)
        else
        print("> Permission Denied")
        disk.eject(sideIn)
        end
    end
end
```

When there's no disk inserted, it throws an error:

```
.temp:15: attempt to compare string with number expected, got string
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I throwed in a nil checker but it seems to not work. Any ideas on how could I fix this? I've been trying for at least half an hour now, and I still have no clue.

Comment: Remove `local` from `local code = tonumber(code)`

Answer (score 3):

In this section:

```
    local code = fs.open("disk/passcode.lua", "r").readAll() --(1)
    if code == nil then
    local code = 0 --(2)
    else
    local code = tonumber(code) --(3)
    end
```

It first makes a new local variable with `local code = ...`. In the new block that you create with the `if`, you *also* create new local variables with `local code = ...`. Since it has the same name as the local before it, it "masks" it, prohibiting you from accessing the first `code` in the rest of the block. The value that you assign 0 to is not the same variable outside the `if`, so the first `code` is unaffected. At `else` the block for the second `code` ends and the same thing happens between `else` and `end` when the condition is false. To not assign the values `0` or `tonumber(code)` to new variables, you have to remove the `local` from `local code = ...`. So the following is what it should be:

```
local level = 3 -- Required access level
local sideIn = "bottom" -- Keycard Input Side
local sideOut = "right" -- Redstone output side
local rsTime = 3 -- Redstone time
while true do
    if disk.isPresent(sideIn) then
        term.clear()
        term.setCursorPos(1,1)
        local code = fs.open("disk/passcode.lua", "r").readAll()
        if code == nil then
            code = 0
        else
            code = tonumber(code)
        end
        if code >= level then
            print("> Access Granted")
            disk.eject(sideIn)
            rs.setOutput(sideOut,true)
            sleep(rsTime)
            rs.setOutput(sideOut,false)
        else
            print("> Permission Denied")
            disk.eject(sideIn)
        end
    end
end
```